# get small sample database from original database without harming data integrity

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I have a big database that contains around 10M nodes and edges.

I want to get a small portion of this database. I want my database to be consistent. Is there any script for that?

It is interesting that even for SQL databases I couldn't find a script or tool for that purpose.

thanks

Comment: How do you define "small sample"? Also, why are you concerned that getting a sample would affect data integrity?

Comment: for example, let's say the whole database is 100 GB. You need at most 1 GB sized data. The data should be consistent. For example, if there is an edge which connects node A and node B, the data SHOULD have node A and node B

Comment: Relationships in Neo4j can only connect existing nodes, so there's no way to have dangling edges that lack end nodes. At least in that respect getting a subset of the db will be consistent. Whether it makes sense according to your data model is another thing (nodes that require connection to other nodes to have meaning).

Answer (score 1):

There is no tool for that.

But you can use the [apoc.meta.schema](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/database-introspection/meta/) procedure to get metadata about your DB's nodes (labels, properties, etc.), relationships (type, properties, etc.), and the connections between them. The resulting map is pretty easy to understand.

You would need to examine the result and come up with a Cypher query to get what you want.